# count case with multiple conditions in same row

Tags: sql, count, case, aggregate-functions

I need to export data of status from `s.status` column like

```
select s.name,
    count(CASE WHEN s.STATUS = 'Active' THEN 1 END) AS Active_count,
    count(CASE WHEN s.STATUS = 'Expired' THEN 1 END) AS Expired_count,
    count(CASE WHEN s.STATUS = 'In Progress' THEN 1 END) AS InProgress_count
from my.table s
group by s.name,s.status
```

I expect it to be counted in one row but instead I am getting smthing like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4wyc.png

Can anyone help me write it so I can get the data in one row ?

Thank you

Comment: Remove s.STATUS from the GROUP BY!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove s.status from your group by